# NoClassDefFoundError in a WAR in an EAR

Tags: java, classloader, war, noclassdeffounderror, ear

I have an EAR that has a WAR inside, which has a jar inside it's WEB-INF/lib/. However, the class in that jar cannot be located (throws NoClassDefFoundError). I've verified that the class is indeed in that jar by doing javap -classpath

Any ideas why?

I'm on glassfish.

Comment: maybe you have other versions of that jar and class loader loads the one without the that class? what jar file is it? is it your project jar or sth common?

Comment: Can you put the stack trace here ? There is a difference between ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError. The class which you checked actually refers another class which is not there in your war/ear libraries folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For some strange reason, the classes being loaded failed to get loaded due to some missing classes. i.e. I have a ClassA and it was loading ClassB. ClassB depends on ClassC. But since ClassC was not in my classpath, ClassB's class was not properly loaded. Thus, accessing ClassB from ClassA threw NoClassDefFoundError.